# How to return object from nested json

Tags: json, swift, api

I have nested JSON and I'm trying to return an object and update UI. However, I can access properties only from ***Result*** array, but can't reach ***Step*** from ***AnalyzedInstactions***.

Here are classes that represent data in the JSON. Generated it with https://app.quicktype.io

```
import UIKit

    class ResultArray: Codable {
    var results = [Result]() 
} 
class Result: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {

    var title: String = ""
    var image = ""
    var readyInMinutes: Int? = 0
    var servings: Int? = 0
    var cuisines = [String]()
    var dishTypes = [String]()
    var diets = [String]()
    var occasions = [String]()
    var analyzedInstructions = [AnalyzedInstruction]()
    
    var description: String {
        return "\nResults - Name: \(title), Summary: \(String(describing: readyInMinutes ?? nil)), \(String(describing: servings ?? nil)) "
    }
}
// MARK: - Steps

class AnalyzedInstruction: Codable {
    var name: String? = ""
    var steps = [Step]()
}

class Step: Codable {
    var number: Int = 0
    var step: String = ""
}
```

Here is my parse method

```
 private func parse(data: Data) -> [Result] {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let result = try decoder.decode(ResultArray.self, from: data)
            return result.results
        } catch {
            print("JSON Error: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you access step like this ```result.results[0].analyzedInstructions[0].step``` in ```parse()``` method?

Comment: And how do you want to access it? It’s an array property inside another array so this can be handled in many ways depending on the end goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this simple code to access your steps from AnalyzedInstructions:

```
            let results: [Result] = parse(data: theData)
            
            if let firstResult = results.first {
                if let firstAnaInst = firstResult.analyzedInstructions.first {
                    for step in firstAnaInst.steps {
                        print("--> step.step: \(step.step)   step.number: \(step.number)")
                    }
                } else { print(" NO analyzedInstructions") }
            } else { print(" NO results") }
```

if you want all steps:

```
            for result in results {
                for anaInst in result.analyzedInstructions {
                    for step in anaInst.steps {
                        print("--> step.step: \(step.step)   step.number: \(step.number)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

PS: if appropriate, you may consider using `struct` instead of `class` for your json models.